# Angular- How to fetch a particular param from a URL in Angular

Tags: angular, url

hello everyone i have an issue regarding URL. I want to fetch id i.e:2 from given below URL.

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2

Comment: Please add some additional information on what you have tried so far and didn't work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make use of ActivateRoute to get the params from the url.
example below from angular docs:

```
 constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const heroId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.hero$ = this.service.getHero(heroId);
  }
```